# Can you read/write a specific bit from a byte/int/

Tags: c#, byte, bit

Coming from PLC I'm used to being able to write an individual bit.
if I want to write to the third bit of a byte I do the following:

```
byte Var1;
Var1.X2 := true;
```

Is there a similar way in C# to easily write to a certain bit of a byte/int?

For now, I'm using the sum to get a similar result (bit1 -> +1, bit3 -> +4, ...), but being able to read/write to a specific byte would be easier.

Comment: `Var1 |= (1 << 2)` will set Bit2, `Var1 &= ~(1 << 2)` will clear it.

Comment: Typically would be to use something like `Var1 | 0x04` (bitwise OR) to set a specific bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some bit arithmetic's via [bitwise and shift operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators):

```cs
byte b = 8;
string binary = Convert.ToString(b, 2);
Console.WriteLine(b);
b|= 1 << 1;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(b, 2));
```

Or using [binary literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#integer-literals):

```cs
byte b = 8;
string binary = Convert.ToString(b, 2); 
Console.WriteLine(binary); // 1000
b |= 0b_0010;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(b, 2)); // 1010
b &= 0b_1101;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(b, 2)); // 1000
```

Comment: Works but its evil to use keywords as variable name ;)